# Jquery text field value by name

Tags: jquery

Jquery how to iterate and get value from hidden array of fields **name="tag[]"**

I am using following tagedit plugin but could not found the method how to get tokenzie values.

http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/

```
<ul id="sel_rc" class="no-bulls">
<li>
<ul class="tagedit-list ">
<li class="tagedit-listelement tagedit-listelement-old">
<span dir="ltr">none</span>

   <input type="hidden" value="none" name="tag[]">

<a class="tagedit-close" title="Remove from list.">x</a>
</li>
<li class="tagedit-listelement tagedit-listelement-old">
<span dir="ltr">r2</span>

   <input type="hidden" value="r2" name="tag[]">

<a class="tagedit-close" title="Remove from list.">x</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if `[]` are valid in an attribute value, try this:

```
var hiddenValues = $('input[type="hidden"][name^="tag"]').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: this is more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate them like any other element:

```
$("[name='tag[]']").each(function() {
   console.log($(this).val()); // none, r2
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute selector **[`[attribute='value']`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** . And you can iterate them using jQuery **[`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** method

```
$('input[name="tag[]"]').each(function(){
      console.log(this.value); 
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/2cfgN/)